# Multi-Container Docker on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've can't seem to get my head around the Dockerrun.aws.json file, which is needed to run a multi-container docker environment on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Everything works fine locally, when I run my app through Docker-Compose. The following is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  interfaceserver:
    build: .
    command: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 restbench.asgi:channel_layer
    user: app
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
  workerserver:
    build: .
    user: app
    working_dir: /app
    command: python manage.py runworker
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
  database:
    image: postgres:9.5
  redis:
    image: redis:3.0-alpine
```

Essentially I am trying to run four services. A Interface-Server, a Worker-Server, a Postgres Database and a Redis Server. The Interface-Server and the Worker-Server and my own Django Builds from a local Dockerfile which are in the same directory as the docker-compose.yml

Now I am trying to deploy my app to Elastic Beanstalk and, from what I understand, I need a Dockerrun.aws.json, which is the same as a docker-compose.yml, just for AWS. I try to read the docs from EBS, but as I mentioned above I can't get my head around the part where I specify the Interface- and Worker-Server. The Database and Redis part is easy, but I don't understand how to specify how to build these two servers in the json file for AWS.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't build images from Dockerfile anymore in "AWSEBDockerrunVersion: 2". It is possible if we have a single container setup with single Dockerfile by using "AWSEBDockerrunVersion: 1".

In your case, you have to build & push images by your own or let your CI server do it. Define the images in your Dockerrun.aws.json v2.

**Ref from AWS docs -**

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun
- **Docker Images** - 
  The Multicontainer Docker platform for Elastic Beanstalk requires images to be prebuilt and stored in a public or private online image repository.
  Building custom images during deployment with a Dockerfile is not supported by the multicontainer Docker platform on Elastic Beanstalk. Build your images and deploy them to an online repository before creating an Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Comment: Ah that explains a lot. I kind of understood that this is possible, but I thought the Dockerrun.aws.json can be written 100% from a docker-compose.yml.

Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/docker-multicontainer-migration.html), Amazon Linux 2 now supports docker-compose files and doesn't have the limitation of needing prebuilt images for Multi-Container Docker environments anymore.

> The Multi-container Docker platform on Amazon Linux AMI requires that you specify prebuilt application images to run as containers. After migrating, you will no longer have this limitation, because the Amazon Linux 2 Docker platform also allows Elastic Beanstalk to build your container images during deployment.

...

> The Docker Compose tool uses the docker-compose.yml file for configuration of your application services. This file replaces your Dockerrun.aws.json v2 file in your application project directory and application source bundle.

We haven't migrated our environments yet, but that sounds promising.